# Install packages to Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

Good evening.... I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04LTS on my PC. I want to install Edubuntu packages on this OS. I have a disk of IT@School Edubuntu 10.04. Can I install packages from this Disk?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend that you install packages that were meant for 12.04 and not ones from 10.04.

As it is, all of the packages that Edubuntu uses are in the official Ubuntu repos. You can install these packages with one of the following commands:

- `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-edu-preschool`
- `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-edu-primary` (Ages 6-12)
- `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-edu-secondary` (Ages 13-18)
- `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-edu-tertiary` (University level)
- `sudo apt-get install edubuntu-desktop` (for all applications)

See [here](https://edubuntu.org/download) for more info.

Comment: I'd also add these are different versions, and have distinct repos, and mixing them is a VERY bad idea